# How to pass your own -H flag to a nagios plugin?

Tags: nagios

Looking [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/macros.html) on the nagios docs I see that it's standard practice to pass a hostaddress macro to your commands with the `-H` flag.

What if your command already has a `-H` flag however?  It's not clear to me how you would do this.  I'm sure this wouldn't work for instance (using the doc's example as a starting point, and assuming `check_ping` works like this):

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.1.2 -H my_personal_flag -w 100.0,90% -c 200.0,60%
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "your command already has a -H flag?" You'd only need to supply it one time. Also, what is "my_personal_flag" in this context? -H should be fed a host name or IP address. I will update my answer if your responses warrant follow up.

Comment: @theterribletrivium what I mean is, suppose the check_ping command itself had a -H flag for some reason.  How would you then pass both it and the HOSTADDRESS?  They both use -H, so it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Now that I read things again, I think I see what the trouble is.  I was used to looking at the check_npre command, which uses a -H flag, and assumed somehow that all nagios commands used that flag to determine which host to run on.  My mistake, thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool, kind of confused why you flagged the other answer as answering your question, but you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define a new custom command using the same plugin that the existing command does. In this command you can pass to the -H switch something other than an actual $HOSTADDRESS$, like $ARG1$ or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring Nagios, you would typically want to use the $HOSTADDRESS$ macro. They are essentially variables internal to Nagios and enumerated at run time. This allows the commands to run with no further interaction from you, as Nagios will find the hostname or IP in your configuration and replace $HOSTADDRESS$ with the specific system's information. You also can only pass -H one time to Nagios.

Here is an example I found online that will hopefully demonstrate:

command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 100.0,90% -c 200.0,60%

If you wanted to run this check one time, you could run the same command but replace $HOSTADDRESS$ with a specific IP, like so:

$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.0.1 -w 100.0,90% -c 200.0,60%